# How to randomly assign text to JButton

Tags: java, swing, random, jbutton

I am writing a math application which will randomly generate a number.  I want to randomly assign that number to one of four buttons. The other three buttons will also be assign a number randomly. What I want is: Anytime the program runs, It will assign the number to a different button as text.

Right now my code only assign the random number to `buttonOne`(which I do not want). Please help.

```
private void generateFourNumberForSelection(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) 
{
   int total = firstNumber + secondNumber;
   buttonOne.setText("" + total);
   buttonTwo.setText("" + (total + 3));
   buttonThree.setText("" + (total - 2));
   buttonFour.setText("" + (total + 5));
}
```

Comment: Can you show the complete code? I am able to get this working on my system.

Comment: Can you show us the output of the program on your computer at least?

Comment: it will be lot easier to do with array of JButtons

Comment: @DanVu check my answer - you will get rough idea from that

Answer (score 0):

This can only happen if `buttonOne`, `buttonTwo`, `buttonThree` and `buttonFour` reference the same `JButton`

Comment: I mean anytime I run the program, it will randomly assign the "total" to a difference button as text.  Right now it will assign the "total" to buttonOne as text.  I do not want that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get an rough idea from below code snippet:

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton(4);  // array of buttons
buttons[0] = new JButton("");
.... do same for 1 and 2 buttons
....
buttons[3] = new JButton("");
/******* buttons intialized*********/

// generating random index - using which we will be setting text on random button
Random r = new Random(4);
int rand = r.nextInt();
buttons[rand] = buttons[rand].setText("" + total);  // setting total on random button
```